# Finding all tables with matching columns

Tags: sql

I have 81 tables where I want to find matching columns and output a list like:

```
"columnName" found in 3 tables:
table1
table2
table3

"columnName2" found in 4 tables:
table1
table3
table4
table5
```

Comment: Answers here are likely to be platform specific. Please specify the platform you're using.

Comment: I'm using phpMyAdmin.

Just to be a little bit more clear, I'm not looking for any specific column, just any _columns_ which can be found in 2 or more tables.

Comment: phpMyAdmin is an application to manage a MySQL or MariaDB database; it's not the database platform itself. Probably you're using one of those; you can see which one and version information from the main phpMyAdmin page (on the right there is much version information for the database server, PHP, and web server).

Answer (score 0):

The table `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` is a system table which contains all columns for all tables. You can look at it by selecting from it.

For your question, you should try this :

```
select I.Column_name,
table_name,
table_count
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS I
inner join 
(
Select Column_name,
count(*) as table_count
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
group by Column_name) as T on T.Column_name = I.Column_name
```

You will have a table with, for each column_name, the tables, and the count in the column `table_count`.

I ust don't know how to output a list. You should put it on excel then if you want to format it I guess ..

Tell me if you have problem !

Answer (score 0):

Below Query should give you the desired result. Let me know if you face any issues. You can modify script if you want to be specific about the single database

This query provides you **Column Name** - **Concatinated Table Names** - **Number of Tables**

```
SELECT t.CNAME AS ColumnName, STUFF(
(SELECT ',' + S.TNAME
FROM 
(
    SELECT  C.NAME AS CNAME , T.NAME AS TNAME
    FROM SYS.OBJECTS AS T
    JOIN SYS.COLUMNS AS C
    ON T.OBJECT_ID=C.OBJECT_ID 
    WHERE T.TYPE_DESC='USER_TABLE' 
)s
WHERE s.CNAME = t.CNAME
FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'') AS TablesUsed,
COUNT(t.TNAME)
FROM 
(
    SELECT  C.NAME AS CNAME , T.NAME AS TNAME
    FROM SYS.OBJECTS AS T
    JOIN SYS.COLUMNS AS C
    ON T.OBJECT_ID=C.OBJECT_ID 
    WHERE T.TYPE_DESC='USER_TABLE' 
)t
GROUP BY t.CNAME
HAVING COUNT(t.TNAME) > 1
ORDER BY COUNT(t.TNAME) DESC
```